# Sending commands via SSH with expect script

Tags: ssh, expect

In a [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648559/using-if-else-in-expect-script) I was kindly provided with a solution to a dilemma I was having with expect and if/else statements (basically, my lack of knowledge in how they're written). The script I was given works with one exception: If I cleanly connect to a remote host the `exit` command is not sent which will close that connection and move onto the next host in the list.

This is the functional part of the script:

```
while {[gets $file1 host] != -1} {
    puts $host
    spawn -noecho ssh $host
    expect {
        "continue connecting" {
            send "yes\r"
            expect {
                "current" {
                    send -- $pw2\r
                    exp_continue
                } 
                "New password" {
                    send -- $pw1\r
                    exp_continue
                } 
                "Retype new password" {
                    send -- $pw1\r
                    exp_continue
                }
                msnyder
            }
            send "exit\r"
        }
    }
    interact
}
```

When I'm connected to the host I expect to see the standard Linux prompt: [username@host ~]$. At least, that's *our* standard prompt. The prompt is preceded by a banner. Might that be throwing a kink into this? I wouldn't think so since I'm only looking for "continue connecting" from the RSA fingerprint prompt and that is within text spread across multiple lines. I would think that expect is intelligent enough to ignore any scrolling text and only look at text in prompts that are looking for input.

I considered passing the `exit` command as an argument for the `ssh $host` command, but expect doesn't seem to like that.

Can someone now assist me in getting the `exit` command to be sent properly?

UPDATE: I've added the `exp_internal 1` option to the script to see what it is doing and it seems to only ever be matching "continue connecting" even at the user prompt once an SSH connection is established. It doesn't appear to be executing the next comparison for "msnyder". http://pastebin.com/kEGH3yUY

UPDATE2: I'm making progress. Based on [Glenn Jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman)'s script below, I was able to get this working until the password prompt appears:

```
set prompt {\$ $}
set file1 [open [lindex $argv 0] r]
set pw1 [exec cat /home/msnyder/bin/.pw1.txt]
set pw2 [exec cat /home/msnyder/bin/.pw2.txt]

while {[gets $file1 host] != -1} {
    puts $host
    spawn -noecho ssh -q $host
    expect {
        "continue connecting" {
            send "yes\r"
            expect {
                "current" {
                    send -- $pw2\r
                    exp_continue
                }
                "New password" {
                    send -- $pw1\r
                    exp_continue
                }
                "Retype new password" {
                    send -- $pw1\r
                    exp_continue
                }
                -re $prompt {
                    send -- exit\r
                    expect eof
                }
            }
        } -re $prompt {
            send -- exit\r
            expect eof
        }
    }
}
```

I have explicitly told it to send the exit command twice rather than trying the short-circuit method that Glenn used (it didn't seem to work per my comment under his answer).

What is now happening, is that it will loop through the list of hosts, send 'yes' to the RSA fingerprint prompt and then send 'exit' to the command prompt. However, when it hits a server that needs to have the password set it stops. It seems to eventually time out and then restarts with the next host. The current password is not being sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've sorted out the answer. After looking at Glenn's script below it occurred to me that each block is a separate if/else when instead I need the password section to act as a single block and the exit to act as the else. This is what I now have:

```
set prompt {\$ $}
set file1 [open [lindex $argv 0] r]
set pw1 [exec cat /home/msnyder/bin/.pw1.txt]
set pw2 [exec cat /home/msnyder/bin/.pw2.txt]

while {[gets $file1 host] != -1} {
    puts $host
    spawn -noecho ssh -q $host
    expect {
        -re $prompt {
            send -- exit\r
            expect eof
        }
        "current" {
                send -- $pw2\r
                expect "New password"
                send -- $pw1\r
                expect "Retype new password"
                send -- $pw1\r
        }
        "continue connecting" {
            send "yes\r"
            expect {
                "current" {
                    send -- $pw2\r
                    expect "New password"
                    send -- $pw1\r
                    expect "Retype new password"
                    send -- $pw1\r
                }
                -re $prompt {
                    send -- exit\r
                    expect eof
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It addresses four situations:

1. I do NOT have to accept the RSA fingerprint OR change my password.
2. I do NOT have to accept the RSA fingerprint but DO have to change my password.
3. I DO have to accept the RSA fingerprint AND change my password.
4. I DO have to accept the RSA fingerprint but NOT change my password.

Answer (score 1):

```
# a regular expression that matches a dollar sign followed by a space 
# anchored at the end of the string
set prompt {\$ $}  

while {[gets $file1 host] != -1} {
    puts $host
    spawn -noecho ssh $host
    expect {
        "continue connecting" {
            send "yes\r"
            expect {
                # ...snipped...
                -re $prompt
            }
        }
        -re $prompt
    }
    send -- exit\r
    expect eof
}
```

We've moved the "exit" to a place where it will be executed if you match either "comtinue connecting" or if you log in directly to your prompt.

---

Nice answer but I hate seeing code cut and pasted. One comment and a bit of refactoring: When you hit the "current" block, you change the password but never exit. It occurs to be that each scenario should end with you seeing the prompt and exiting:

```
while {[gets $file1 host] != -1} {
    puts $host
    spawn -noecho ssh -q $host
    expect {
        "continue connecting" {
            send "yes\r"
            exp_continue
        }
        "current" {
            send -- $pw2\r
            expect "New password"
            send -- $pw1\r
            expect "Retype new password"
            send -- $pw1\r
            exp_continue
        }
        -re $prompt
    }
    send -- exit\r
    expect eof
}
```

If you see "continue connecting", you send yes and then wait to see "current" or the prompt.
If you see "current" you change the password and then wait to see the prompt.
If you see the prompt, the expect comment ends and the next thing you do is exit.

Comment: That still isn't sending the exit at the prompt. This is what I have based on the above: http://pastebin.com/eb7NwTfJ There is one line that I'm not sure about; the first `-re $prompt`. Because of where you snipped the code I can't tell if that is where it belongs.

Comment: What I'm seeing happen is that while logged into the remote server the next host in the loop is being sent rather than the exit command.